# endless browser game while loop

Tags: php

I'm trying to design a PHP browser game just for fun and practice. I'm currently working on the combat script and I encountered an endless loop. I can't figure out the reason why it's happening. Anyways, here's the code:

```
<?php
session_start();

// Script PHP pentru simularea luptelor single player

/*
    1 = Magic
    2 = Attack
    3 = Defence
    5 = Maximum HP
    6 = Current HP
    4 = Gold coins
    17 = Experience
*/

require_once("config.php");

$username = $_SESSION['username'];
$query = ("SELECT id FROM users WHERE username = '$username'");
$user_id = mysql_query($query) or die (mysql_error());

// Momentan monstrii sunt alesi in mod aleatoriu
$query = ("SELECT id FROM monsters ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1");
$monster_id = mysql_query($query) or die (mysql_error());

$query = ("SELECT value FROM user_stats WHERE stat_id = 6 AND user_id = '$user_id'");
$player_hp = mysql_query($query) or die (mysql_error());

$query = ("SELECT value FROM monster_stats WHERE stat_id = 5 AND monster_id = '$monster_id'");
$monster_hp = mysql_query($query) or die (mysql_error());

if ($player_hp <= 0)
{
    $query = ("SELECT value FROM user_stats WHERE stat_id = 4 AND user_id = '$user_id'");
    $player_gc = mysql_query($query) or die (mysql_error());

    $query = ("SELECT value FROM monster_stats WHERE stat_id = 4 AND user_id = '$monster_id'");
    $monster_gc = mysql_query($query) or die (mysql_error());

    $query = ("SELECT value FROM user_stats WHERE stat_id = 17 AND user_id = '$monster_id'");
    $player_exp = mysql_query($query) or die (mysql_error());

    $query = ("SELECT value FROM monster_stats WHERE stat_id = 17 AND monster_id = '$monster_id'");
    $monster_exp = mysql_query($query) or die (mysql_error());

    $player_gc = $player_gc + $monster_gc;
    $player_exp = $player_exp + $monster_exp;

    // item drop trebuie facut

    echo "Congratulations! You won the battle and you gained " . $monster_gc . " gold coins and " . $monster_exp . " experience points.";
}
elseif ($monster_hp <= 0)
{
    echo "You lost the battle.";
}
else
{
    $query = ("SELECT value FROM user_stats WHERE stat_id = 1 AND user_id = '$user_id'");
    $player_magic = mysql_query($query) or die (mysql_error());

    $query = ("SELECT value FROM monster_stats WHERE stat_id = 1 AND monster_id = '$monster_id'");
    $monster_magic = mysql_query($query) or die (mysql_error());

    $query = ("SELECT value FROM user_stats WHERE stat_id = 2 AND user_id = '$user_id'");
    $player_attack = mysql_query($query) or die (mysql_error());

    $query = ("SELECT value FROM monster_stats WHERE stat_id = 2 AND monster_id = '$monster_id'");
    $monster_attack = mysql_query($query) or die (mysql_error());

    $query = ("SELECT value FROM user_stats WHERE stat_id = 3 AND user_id = '$user_id'");
    $player_defence = mysql_query($query) or die (mysql_error());

    $query = ("SELECT value FROM monster_stats WHERE stat_id = 3 AND monster_id = '$monster_id'");
    $monster_defence = mysql_query($query) or die (mysql_error());

    $turn = rand(0,1);
    while (($player_hp > 0) && ($monster_hp > 0) &&($turn < 6))
    {
        $turn++;

        // Player turn
        if ($turn % 2 == 0)
        {
            echo $monster_hp . "<br>";
            $monster_hp -= ($player_attack + $player_magic / 2 - $monster_defence - $monster_magic / 2);
            var_dump ($monster_hp);
        }
        // Monster turn
        else
        {
            echo $player_hp . "<br>";
            $player_hp -= ($monster_attack + $monster_magic / 2 - $player_defence - $player_magic / 2);
            var_dump ($player_hp);
        }
    }
}
```

?>

The while is down in the else. I know that MySQL is depreciated. Thanks!

Comment: PS: the game will be boring! :D

Comment: try replacing $player_hp - with $player_hp -= maybe ? and same for monster_hp...

Comment: Not only is it boring, it's got SQL injection vulnerabilities you could drive a truck through.

Comment: In addition to @Wooble's comment, I'd advise you to use MySQLi (with prepared statements) or PDO instead of the deprecated MySQL extension which will be removed in near future!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Are you after this (operator is `-=` not `-`):

```
// Player turn
if ($turn % 2 == 0)
{
    $monster_hp -= ($player_attack + $player_magic / 2 - $monster_defence - $monster_magic / 2);
}
// Monster turn
else
{
    $player_hp -= ($monster_attack + $monster_magic / 2 - $player_defence - $player_magic / 2);
}
```

**-edit-** if your variable is `Resource id #5` etc, it means you haven't correctly retried your MySQL data from **PHP**. Try this:

```
$query = ("SELECT value FROM user_stats WHERE stat_id = 3 AND user_id = '$user_id'");
$player_defence = mysql_query($query) or die (mysql_error());
$player_defence = mysql_fetch_assoc($player_defence);
$player_defence = $player_defence['value'];
```

You'll need to do that (or something similar) for every query result you're getting. It converts your query result to an associate array then to the variable you need.

Manual: http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-assoc.php

Comment: That was one of the problems. However the loop is still endless. :(

Comment: put a manual limit onto your while loop of say 50, then `var_dump` each variable on each loop to see what's going on in your logic

Comment: @SporeDev: Add the following statement in your `while` loop: `var_dump( ($player_hp > 0) && ($monster_hp > 0) )` -- what does it output?

Comment: If I put that as the condition I get: bool(true)

Comment: @SporeDev what are the values of $monster_hp and $player_hp before the start of the while loop ?

Comment: I'll edit my question in a bit with the changed that I made. Here is what I get now: Resource id #7
float(7.5) Resource id #8
float(11.5) 7.5
float(8) 11.5
float(15) 8
float(8.5) 15
float(18.5)

Comment: The player HP should be 100 initially.

Comment: The problem is that the user's id is Resource id #5 instead of 12. I echoed the $username variable and it's correct. Replaced the variable with the actual user in phpmyadmin and it gets 12. Why does it get Resource id #5 instead of 12 in PHP?

Comment: updated answer with some info about getting your correct values

Answer (score 2):

In your while loop you never actually CHANGE the HPs of the monsters and players:

```
$monster_hp - ($player_attack + $player_magic / 2 - $monster_defence - $monster_magic / 2);
```

Did you mean to use something like this instead:

```
$monster_hp -= ($player_attack + $player_magic / 2 - $monster_defence - $monster_magic / 2);
```

The `-=` operator is really a quick way of programming `equals itself minus...`:

```
// The following lines are identical in logic:
$var-=1
$var=$var-1;
```